# How to play an Animation after an key (in my case , F) is pressed in Roblox

Tags: luau, roblox-studio

I tried to play an Animation with the available documentation. It turned out to be this :

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local player = Players:FindFirstChild("Builderman")

local character = player.Character
local humanoid = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://16221843862" 

local animationTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
animationTrack:Play()
```

It didn't work. I think the LoadAnimation is not valide anymore.

I need help for this. I'm very new to Roblox's Luau

Comment: you can use `Humanoid:LoadAnimation`

Comment: Hello Ermi, I can't do anything but say it doesn't work for me. Can u offer an solution for this? Very Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Updated got R15 animation.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local playerName = "Builderman"
local animationId = "rbxassetid://16221843862"

local player = Players:FindFirstChild(playerName)

if player then
    local character = player.Character

    if character then
        local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")

        if humanoid then
            local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
            animation.AnimationId = animationId

            local humanoidDescription = humanoid:FindFirstChild("HumanoidDescription")
            if humanoidDescription then
                humanoidDescription:Destroy() -- Remove HumanoidDescription for R6 avatars
            end

            local animationTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)

            if animationTrack then
                animationTrack:Play()
            else
                warn("Failed to load animation track.")
            end
        else
            warn("Humanoid not found in character.")
        end
    else
        warn("Character not found for player '" .. playerName .. "'.")
    end
else
    warn("Player '" .. playerName .. "' not found.")
end
```

Comment: still doesn't work. IDK WHY IT IS NOT WORKING REEEEEEEEEEE

Comment: Did you check the animationId, check it from the website? It should work.

Comment: Hi Ermi. i tried something on my own side. I made an new code but its popping with this error :  Workspace.Script:4: attempt to index nil with 'Character' -

Comment: Well that shows the `player` variable is valid, but the `player.Character` expression is resulting in `nil`. This can happen if the player is not in the game or if their character has not been loaded yet.

Comment: Hi Ermi. I switched my animation from R15 to R6. So, I can make the code for the animation trigger but my Avatar is not able to do the animation or smth.

Comment: If i am write this should work for R15.